# right scroll bar appearing and need to remove it

Tags: css, scrollbar

I'm a newbie and need to remove the scroll bar at the bottom of this website.

I also need the body to be centered.

http://selfcateringholidaycottagecornwall.seesites.biz/

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

First: what screen size are you on? 
The reason that you get a scrollbar at the bottom of the page probably is because your screen resolution is low. 
When I go to your link, I don't have a scrollbar (this is at screen resolution: 1920x1080 and with Firefox 28.0).

A possible solution is to use the `max-width:` attribute to your 's to prevent your website from being too large.

Is this what you mean? If not, could you clarify your problem?